# Entity Framework unit test (or similar) to ensure that when using a DbSet, an particular extension method is always called

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I want to enforce a requirement that any time you interact with db.Users, you are REQUIRED to call a particular extension method. Below is some more specific information.

When interacting with my database via Entity Framework, I have the following query (db is a DbContext instance):

```
var user = db.Users
              .FromOrganisation(someId)
              .FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == someUsername);
```

This query will vary all of the time throughout the application (WHERE clause will often be different etc.). Because of this, I want to make it a requirement that you must always call the FromOrganisation() extension method so that all data returned is filtered by Organisation first.

This is to prevent anyone ever seeing data belonging to a different organisation, but I'm stuck on exactly how to achieve it.

Is there a unit test I can write to alert the developer that the Users DbSet is being used without filtering by organisation? If not, are there any alternative routes I could take to achieve the same level of protection.

In case it's important, the extension method itself looks like this:

```
public static IQueryable<User> FromOrganisation(this IQueryable<User> u, int organisationId)
{
    return u.Where(x => x.OrganisationId == organisationId);
}
```

**My final solution**

I changed my context as follows:

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

Became:

```
[Obsolete("MUST use service!")]
public DbSet<User> UsersUnfiltered { get; set; }


public IQueryable<User> Users(int id)
{
    #pragma warning disable 618
    return UsersUnfiltered.Where(x => x.OrganisationId == id);
    #pragma warning restore 618
}
```

What this does is encourages you to use the Users method to return a filtered list of Users by organisation. This can be further filtered, joined, and queried etc as normal.

You also have access to the UsersUnfiltered DbSet if you need it, but if you use this then a compiler warning is generated. You can suppress this warning by accessing it inside of the #pragma warning disable 618 directives.

With this in place, you have the code on your side to prevent you ever using the Users data without filtering by organisation, unless you really mean to do it.

Thanks to @mark_h for helping me reach this solution.

Comment: Do you need to expose the `Users` set? What if you only fetch users via a `IQueryable<User> GetOrganisationUsers(int id)`?

Comment: This is a very interesting point. My context exposes a list of DbSet<EntityName> properties at present. However, I use these not only for querying, but also for adding new records to the database, so I think they would have to be exposed somewhere along the line.

Comment: You could add an `AddUser` method to the context. Another option is to define global filters with EntityFramework.DynamicFilters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An issue with what you are proposing is that if you could enforce its use, you would have to enforce it every time you wanted to sub-query a set of users even after you had done your initial query from the context i.e.

```
var allUsersOfOrganisation1 = db.Users.FromOrganisation(1)
// some code...
var someUsersOfOrganisation1 = allUsersOfOrganisation1.FromOrganisation(1).Where(...)
```

If you enforced the use of your extension method how would you differentiate between a query to a set containing all users and a filtered subset?

You can achieve the result you are after by wrapping your entity model and only exposing the Users through methods that enforce the unique organisation id;

```
public class WrappedEntities
{
    private MyEntityFramework Entities = new MyEntityFramework();

    //regular public entities
    public DbSet<Organisation> Organisations { get { return Entities.Organisation; } set { Entities.Organisation = value as DbSet<Organisation>; } }

    //Special case
    public IQueryable<User> Users(int id)
    {
        return Entities.Users.Where(x => x.OrganisationId == organisationId);
    }

    //other wrapped methods...
    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return Entities.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

If you gave this class an interface you would also be able to mock it for the purposes of unit testing.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - I implemented this yesterday and it works exactly as it should. I'll post my final solution in my original question. Many thanks for your help.